# Using a mutex in conjunction with shared_ptr to protect data shared across copies

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, c++17, shared-ptr

I have a class whose copies share the same data via `shared_ptr`. Since that data is going to be modified by different threads I'm going to use a mutex in order to protect it, however, it is my understanding that the mutex object has to be the same across different copies in order to work, ignoring the fact that mutexes are not actually copyable.

Therefore I intend to put the mutex into a `shared_ptr` as well. Like so:

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <mutex>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class test {
public:
  auto some_action(int x) -> void {
    std::scoped_lock(*m_store_mutex);

    m_shared_store->push_back(x);
  }

private:
  std::shared_ptr<std::mutex> m_store_mutex { std::make_shared<std::mutex>() };
  std::shared_ptr<std::vector<int>> m_shared_store { std::make_shared<std::vector<int>>() };
};
```

Is this approach valid? It seems to be working but I'd like to be sure.

P.S.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9483657/boostshared-ptr-boostmutex-and-copy-constructor) question is fairly similar to mine, but I do not feel like the answers are quite specific enough.

Comment: Why not simply put the mutex into the object it's supposed to protect?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Well, it is a standard library container for one, although I suppose I could wrap it. Not sure whether which approach would work better.

Comment: Even if it's not convenient to embed the mutex in the same object as the data, why would the method you use for sharing the mutex be any different from the method that you use for sharing the data?

Comment: Typically, you'd want the implementation of your type to internally take care of the proper synchronization rather than rely on the user to not forget to manually wrap the correct synchronization around every place where he happens to do anything with your type. If you want a thread-safe standard container, then build a wrapper around that standard container that only exposes an interface that can actually be made thread-safe and take care of the proper synchronization internally. As Scott Meyers says: *Make your interfaces easy to use correctly but hard to use incorrectly*…

Comment: @SolomonSlow I'm rather new to working with threads so the answer to that is not that obvious to me.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel That is certainly the right approach, but I feel that it would be somewhat overkill for what I'm doing. :)

Comment: I think you have an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. What kind of container are you trying to use to do exactly what in a thread-safe way? In my experience, you'll never want to build a generic "thread-safe container", you'll actually want to build a container specifically for a particular task where thread-safety is a requirement…

Comment: @TonCherAmi, Even if there happens to be some magic in the _implementation_ of the `std::mutex` class, from _your_ point of view, as an application programmer, it's just another object. Your code calls its methods in exactly the same way that it calls the methods of any other object. Your code can make and use pointers and references to a mutex in exactly the same way that it would make and use pointers and references to any other object.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel It is just an `unordered_map` of event listeners, event type to a vector of listeners. It might be accessed from different threads when there's a need for the listeners to be notified of an event.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks for the explanation, that makes it clearer.

Comment: Will this `unordered_map` ever be modified concurrently?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel It might be if there are `subscribe` calls coming in from different threads, which is a certain possibility.

Comment: In this case, you'll probably want to have a look at [`std::shared_mutex`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/shared_mutex). Also, rather than an `std::unordered_map` of vectors, you may want to consider just using an `std::unordered_multimap`. It would seem to me that what you're looking for is a class that wraps an`std::unordered_multimap` to `std::function` objects bundled with an `std::shared_mutex` that supports two operations: `subscribe` and `notify`…

Comment: This class begs to be templated.  You should have a look at libguarded

Answer (score 3):

You may want to consider `std::shared_mutex`
 instead of `std::mutex`.

as per explained by CoryKramer in 
[shared_mutex explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46453028/6943925)

It fits your situation much better than `std::mutex`.